# jQuery .html() Styling issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Hello Stackoverflow.**

Currently I'm working on a small function which gets some messages en returns them by AJAX call. However I have some issues with the Styling which happens after it's inserted.

Normally the DIV's have the height of their content and have a width that it fits the container (100%). However, after the AJAX call I insert the updated HTML; The elements get beside eachother and get the height of their parent.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/live/stream",
        success: function(response) {
            var html_result = '';
            var err = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            if(err.return == 'true'){
                $.each(err.array, function(key, real_value) {
                    var real_value = Object.values(real_value.data);
                    console.log(real_value[1]);
                    if(real_value[1] == '0') {
                        html_result += '<div class="_stream" style="width:100% !important; margin-bottom: 10px; position:relative;">';
                        html_result += '<div class="title"><span class="name">' + real_value[3] + ' </span> schreibt am ' + real_value[6] + '</div>\n';
                        html_result += '<div class="content">' + real_value[4] + '</div>';
                        html_result += '</div><br><br>';
                    }else if(real_value[1] == '1') {
                        html_result += '<div class="_stream action" style="width:100% !important; margin-bottom: 10px; position:relative;">';
                        html_result += '<div class="title"><span class="name">' + real_value[3] + '</span> hat am ' + real_value[6] + '</div>\n';
                        html_result += '<div class="content">' + real_value[4] + '</div>';
                        html_result += '</div><br><br>';
                    }
                });
                $(".streamBox").html(html_result);
            }
        }
    });
```

What I want is that the DIV's get underneath eachother (https://prnt.sc/ijapbv). What they currently do is get beside eachother. (https://prnt.sc/ijanrr)

I tried some inline-css, but this didn't have any effect either. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took me some research, and after the tip of Charles as answer I did find a solution. I had a jQuery Scrollbar plugin on the parent element, which intervened with the post. After removing the initialization on the element, no issues were found.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the markup and styles for the element with class 'streamBox', but the default behavior of block level elements such as divs is to stack on top of each other. This implies that there may be some style overriding this default behavior...

One solution that comes to mind would be to add the following styles/CSS to the streamBox class as follows:

`.streamBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }`

see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A div is a block element.  Check to see if one of your style classes is somehow adding a display style of inline.  I would look at the resulting html in IE or Chrome developer tools.  Maybe it's inheriting something.  Also I don't think you need the \n escape.